# Segement fault with Inversion Counting algorithm

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mergesort

I am working on a program which implements the inversion counting with merge sort algorithm.

When I test my program with given test cases. I experienced segmentation fault which I cannot find the reason.

One test case is shown in the following codes:

```
    int inputArray[5] = {5,4,3,2,1};
    inversionCount Inversion(inputArray, 5);
    count = Inversion.totalinversionCount(0, 4);
```

The program gives the correct answer as 10.

Another test case is:

```
    int inputArray[15] = {9, 12, 3, 1, 6, 8, 2, 5, 14, 13, 11, 7, 10, 4, 0};
    inversionCount Inversion(inputArray, 15);
    count = Inversion.totalinversionCount(0, 14);
```

The program gives an answer as 48, while the correct answer is 56. I tried to debug the program by printing the array[] elements in the class. It seems in the constructor the copied array[] is {9 12 3 1 6 8 2 5 14 13 11 7 10 4 0}. However, when the program steps into counting, the class member array[] changed to {0 12 3 1 6 8 2 5 14 13 11 7 10 4 0}. The first element changed to 0 from 9. I don't know why.

The last test case is:

```
    int inputArray[100] = { 4, 80, 70, 23, 9, 60, 68, 27, 66, 78, 12, 40, 52, 53, 44, 8, 49, 28, 18, 46, 21, 39, 51, 7, 87, 99, 69, 62, 84, 6, 79, 67, 14, 98, 83, 0, 96, 5, 82, 10, 26, 48, 3, 2, 15, 92, 11, 55, 63, 97, 43, 45, 81, 42, 95, 20, 25, 74, 24, 72, 91, 35, 86, 19, 75, 58, 71, 47, 76, 59, 64, 93, 17, 50, 56, 94, 90, 89, 32, 37, 34, 65, 1, 73, 41, 36, 57, 77, 30, 22, 13, 29, 38, 16, 88, 61, 31, 85, 33, 54 };
    inversionCount Inversion(inputArray, 100);
    count = Inversion.totalinversionCount(0, 99);
```

The program runs into segmentation fault in the construction step. The debug shows the program pauses when copying Array[] to array[].

```
Signal received: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)
For program algorithm_design_i_week_1, pid 23,328
You may discard the signal or forward it and you may continue or pause the process
```

My program is given below. Please help me to find out the reason for segmentation fault. Thank you very much.

inversionCount.h

```
#ifndef INVERSIONCOUNT_H
#define INVERSIONCOUNT_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;   

class inversionCount {
private:
    int length;
    int array[];

public:
    inversionCount(int Array[], int Length);
    int splitCount(int first, int mid, int last);
    int totalinversionCount(int first, int last);
};

#endif /* INVERSIONCOUNT_H */
```

inversionCount.cpp

```
#include "inversionCount.h"

inversionCount::inversionCount(int Array[], int Length) {
    length = Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        array[i] = Array[i];
}

int inversionCount::splitCount(int first, int mid, int last) {
    int first1 = first, last1 = mid;
    int first2 = mid + 1, last2 = last;
    int tempArray[length];
    int i = first;
    int totalSplitCount = 0;
    while (i < last && first1 <= last1 && first2 <= last2) {
        if (array[first1] < array[first2]) {
            tempArray[i] = array[first1];
            first1++;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            tempArray[i] = array[first2];
            totalSplitCount += last1 + 1 - first1;   
            first2++;
            i++;
        }           
    }
    while (first1 <= last1) {
        tempArray[i] = array[first1];
        first1++;
        i++;
    }   
    while (first2 <= last2) {
        tempArray[i] = array[first2];
        first2++;
        i++;
    }  
    for (int j = first; j < last + 1; j++) 
        array[j] = tempArray[j];
    return totalSplitCount;
}

int inversionCount::totalinversionCount(int first, int last) {    
    int totalCount = 0;
    if (first < last) {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;
        totalCount = totalinversionCount(first, mid) + totalinversionCount(mid + 1, last) + splitCount(first, mid, last);
    }       

    return totalCount;
}
```

countDriver.cpp

```
#include "inversionCount.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int inputArray[5] = {5,4,3,2,1};

    inversionCount Inversion(inputArray, 5);
    int count = 0;
    count = Inversion.totalinversionCount(0, 4);
    cout<<"The number of inversions is "<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How many elements do you expect are in `int array[];`? (`std::vector` is your friend.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. I still need to learn about std::vector. But when I change int array[] to e.g. int array[100], the program can execute without further problems. @molbdnilo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int array[];` is not legal C++ as the definition of a member variable.  Your compiler must allow it as an extension, but in that case it means "no space is allocated for the array, but we will do something like:

```
A* pA = static_cast<A*>(malloc(sizeof(A) + Length*sizeof(int));
```

You are not doing this, so when you write to the array, you overwrite some random bits of memory, so bad stuff happens.

The best bet is to use `std::vector`.

```
class inversionCount {
private:
    std::vector<int> array;

public:
    inversionCount(int Array[], int Length) : array(Array, Array+Length) {}
    int splitCount(int first, int mid, int last);
    int totalinversionCount(int first, int last);
};
```

One other comment:  it is much better to use `size_t` as the type of lengths and offsets into arrays and containers - it is what the C++ library uses.  `size_t` is an unsigned type so by using the same type as the library, you avoid difficult problems with 'signed/unsigned mismatch'.  (The effects are often not what you would expect.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the problem. It really helps. Could you please provide me some guidances on how to implements the initialization of the vector in the constructor "inversionCount(int Array[], int Length) : array(Array, Array+Length) {}" in the cpp file? Also, the comment on "size_t" is important as well. When the array size increases to 100000, the program gives a negative result for "int" type. Using "size_t" instead of "int" provides correct results.

Comment: I've shown the constructor inline.  If you want it out of line (in the CPP file), then it is just `inversionCount::inversionCount(int Array[], int Length) : array(Array, Array+Length) {}` (and obviously just the declaration that you had originally in the header.)